# How to detect net core 3.1 windows desktop app runtime is installed

Tags: wix

I am trying to detect if the net core 3.1 windows desktop app runtime is installed and not run the installer if it is.

However on a test system that has net core 3.1 windows desktop app runtime installed I can see the installer run and after looking at the log, NetCoreInstalled, evaluates to 0 even though the directory exists. How can I get this working?

```html
<Fragment>

    <util:FileSearch 
      Id="NetCoreInstalled" 
      Variable="NetCoreInstalled"
      Path="[ProgramFiles64Folder]dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App\3.1.0"
      Result="exists" />
    
    <PackageGroup Id="NetCore310x64">


        <ExePackage
     Id="NetCore310x64"
     Cache="no"
     Compressed="yes"
     PerMachine="yes"
     InstallCondition="(VersionNT64) AND (NOT NetCoreInstalled)"
          DetectCondition="NetCoreInstalled"
          InstallCommand="/quiet /passive"
     Vital="yes"
     Permanent="yes"
     SourceFile="..\..\..\Requirements\windowsdesktop-runtime-3.1.0-win-x64.exe"
     Name="Redist\windowsdesktop-runtime-3.1.0-win-x64.exe" />

    </PackageGroup>


  </Fragment>
```

Comment: Where did you find the Conditions such as 'InstallCondition="(VersionNT64) AND (NOT NetCoreInstalled)"'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `DirectorySearch`, not `FileSearch`.

Comment: See https://github.com/dotnet/designs/blob/master/accepted/install-locations.md for the official doc.